# DataGrid returning null selectedItem

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a dojo (1.8.1) DataGrid where I cannot retrieve all the selected items in the DataGrid (roughly 171 records in the grid).  The problem is that some of data returned to selectedItem are null.

Interesting, If i scroll all the way to the bottom of the DataGrid and then run though the code below, I get all the records..This is weird..

```
var gridy = dijit.byId("grid");
var items = gridy.selection.getSelected();
if (items.length) {
  dojo.forEach(items, function(selectedItem) {
   if (selectedItem !== null) {
     dojo.forEach(gridy.store.getAttributes(selectedItem),
            function(attribute){
              var value = gridy.store.getValues(selectedItem, attribute);
              alert('attribute: ' + attribute + ', value: ' + value);
            });
    } 
  });
}
```

So, when all items in the grid are selected (171) I only get 50 items showing as selected and the rest are null for selectedItem variable.  Strange problem, seem like a bug in DataGrid??

Thx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be due to `paging` (see [DataGrid-tutorial at "Paging and Virtual Scrolling"](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/datagrid/)). *"only a small subset of the data is ever rendered at one time"*. Therefore, a nasty workaround could be to set the `rowsPerPage`-property of your `DataGrid` to a high value (like `1000`) when instanciating it.. It should be higher then the expected maximum amount of rows to be displayd in the grid at all ever.

Comment: Thanks!!  I will never have more that around 300 rows of data so this solution works great.  Set rowsPerPage to 1000 and I get all selected rows without scrolling to the bottom.

Comment: Glad i could help :) BTW: I guess even scrolling to the very bottum would get you all items for sure, cause they say it keeps a maximum of three pages at a time. So it depends..